# C:/Users/firmware/Desktop/uc4/New Folder/Inc/ff.h:28:10: fatal error: integer.h: No such file or directory

Tags: stm32, stm32f4

i m working on a project in which i am using stm32f411 nucleo board. in which i face error
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
fatal error: ff.h: No such file or directory    fatfs.h /New Folder/Inc line 56 C/C++ Problem

In file included from C:/Users/firmware/Desktop/uc4/New Folder/Inc/file_functions.h:10:0,
                 from C:/Users/firmware/Desktop/uc4/New Folder/Inc/target_init.h:30,
                 from C:/Users/firmware/Desktop/uc4/New Folder/Inc/Test_functions.h:20,
                 from C:/Users/firmware/Desktop/uc4/New Folder/Inc/UC_Packet_Process.h:20,
                 from C:/Users/firmware/Desktop/uc4/New Folder/Inc/system.h:15,
                 from C:/Users/firmware/Desktop/uc4/New Folder/Inc/Analog_Light.h:15,
                 from ../Src/Analog_Light.c:9:
C:/Users/firmware/Desktop/uc4/New Folder/Inc/fatfs.h:56:10: fatal error: ff.h: No such file or directory
 #include "ff.h"

but the file ff.h is present at location middleware/third_party/FatFs/src

i m using eclipse 
plese anyone tell me as soon as possible what i can do

Answer (score 0):

makes sure that path is included in the "include paths" used by the compiler. Or provide a relative path to that file specifically.

In Keil, you can click "Project->Options" then "c/c++" tab. Then you can look for the "Incl Paths" My project for example has the following:

> "../Inc;v../Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc;
>   ../Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy;
>   ../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L4xx/Include;../Drivers/CMSIS/Include"

verify your middleware/third_party/FatFs/src (or my guess is you might have a match inc folder where the .h file is present). But anyways, find that file, make sure you include the file path so the compiler knows where to find it.

I don't know what tool you are actually using, but most tools have an option to add include paths.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .I am using eclipse tool. and in my peroject these was include before  ../Inc
../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc
../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy
../Middlewares/Third_Party/FatFs/src
../Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/include
../Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS
../Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F
../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include
../Drivers/CMSIS/Include